# What's the easiest way to avoid the double class issue on modules?

Tags: module, css

The module class suffix is added to a module and then to the `div` with the module content within it.  On the second occasion it adds the word/class "custom".

I've always found this a bit of an annoying bug.  Not only because you need to teach clients to use a space for their classes but also because it duplicates any styling.  I believe it's been removed from J4 which makes me happy.

You can avoid the duplicate styling in some cases by not adding a space so your class becomes `customMyClass` instead of `MyClass`

But you have multiple classes there's no easy way around this.  So for example:

`pure-u-md-12-24 pure-u-lg-6-24 pure-u-1`  becomes
`custompure-u-md-12-24 pure-u-lg-6-24 pure-u-1`

Because these classes control the width of the container it can be really problematic.  What's the easiest way to resolve that issue?

Comment: Ditto! Created a content plugin to parse and add a space automatically. That's what I have done - but does sometimes result in double spaces in the very rare instance someone remembers to add a space, which as yet, doesn't appear to cause any issues with any major browser (e.g. `custom  myclass` or `custom myclass`). Unfortunately it's NDA so can only provide some pointers. Or you can probably just override it with a Module Chrome template with a modules.php template - see here under Applying custom Module chrome
 - https://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_way_modules_are_displayed

Comment: I've overridden the module chrome but that only effects the outer div not the inner div.  I only want to effect the inner div.  I'm going to make a plugin to solve the problem.  I'll probably install it on every site!